# Does this series converge $\sum^{\infty}_{m=6} \frac{10^mm!}{(3m)^m}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove whether this sum converges or diverges?

$\sum^{\infty}_{m=6} \frac{10^mm!}{(3m)^m}$.

I assume that I should use the ratio test to check whether the following is smaller than one:

$(\frac{10^{m+1}(m+1)!}{(3m+1)^{m+1}})(\frac{(3m)^m}{10^mm!})$. This I could reduce to:

$\frac{10(m+1)(3m)^m}{(3m+1)^{m+1}}$. From here, I am unsure. can this turn into:

$\frac{(10)(m+1)(m)^m}{(3)(m+1)^{m+1}}$ = $\frac{(10)(m)^m}{(3)(m+1)^m}$? Then this looks to be diverging, correct?

Comment: From the start, the factor $(3m+1)^{m+1}$ should read $$(3(m+1))^{m+1}=3^{m+1}(m+1)^{m+1}$$ hence the ratio to consider is $$\frac{10\cdot m^m}{3\cdot(m+1)^m}$$ Can you conclude?

Answer (score 2):

It diverges trivially, since $\;\dfrac{10^m\,m!}{(3m)^m}\to\infty$.

Indeed, it results from *Stirling's formula* that
$$\frac{10^m\,m!}{(3m)^m}\sim_\infty\frac{10^m\,\sqrt{2\pi m}\,m^m}{(3m)^m\,\mathrm e^m}=\biggl(\frac{10}{3\mathrm e}\biggr)^m\sqrt{2\pi m}\to \infty\enspace\text{since}\quad \frac{10}{3\mathrm e}>1.$$

Comment: There is an even more trivial approach than using Stirling formula...

Comment: Ratio test? Yes, but it involves more calculations. Proving Stirling's formula is not trivial, but using it is.